# 401 Unauthorized Error Using Axios and Firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, axios

I am using firebase and I want to send data from my react app. I installed Axios then made an Axios component and sent data using Axios. But I got 401 unauthorized error

```
purchaseContinueHandler = () => {
        const order = {
            ingredients : this.state.ingredients,
            price : this.state.totalPrice, 
            customer : {
                name : 'Usman',
                address :{
                    street : 'wapda town',
                    zipcode : '54700',
                    country : 'pakistan'
                },
                email : 'usidd@gmail.com'
            },
            deliveryMethod : '30minutes'
         }
            axios.post('/order.json',order).
            then(response => 
                console.log(response)).
                    catch(error => 
                        console.log(error)); // .json to be added for firebase
    }
```

And the security rules for firebase are as follows:

```
  rules_version = '2';
    service cloud.firestore {
      match /databases/{database}/documents {
    
        // This rule allows anyone with your database reference to view, edit,
        // and delete all data in your Firestore database. It is useful for getting
        // started, but it is configured to expire after 30 days because it
        // leaves your app open to attackers. At that time, all client
        // requests to your Firestore database will be denied.
        //
        // Make sure to write security rules for your app before that time, or else
        // all client requests to your Firestore database will be denied until you Update
        // your rules
        match /{document=**} {
          allow read, write: if request.time < timestamp.date(2020, 8, 25);
        }

    }
  }
```

Comment: Unauthorised error came from API. so may be your API needs login token or something like that. Without login token you will get such error from API.

Comment: Do you have any security rule for your Realtime Database?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec yes it allows everyone to edit

Comment: Can you add your security rules code to your question please?

Comment: Thanks. However, these are security rules for Firestore, not for the Realtime Database (they are two different database services). You should, in the Firebase "Database" console panel, switch of DB via the drop-down select box close to the "Database" title.

Comment: I am getting the same error on firestore db.

Answer (score 0):

You most probably have some security rules for the Realtime Database that prevent an unauthenticated user to write to the database. What you have shown in your question are the security rules for [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore), not for the [Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database) (they are two different database services).

Comment: @usmansiddique Hi, did you have time to look at the answer?